# change the look of Gallery selected item

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-adapter

i have "Gallery" on my layout, and i created a class inherits from BaseAdapter, to set it as Gallery adapter

```
GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter
```

and i used it

```
setAdapter(new GalleryAdapter
```

and it works fine.

but now i need to change the selected view within the gallery, i need it within the adapter.

is there anyway to know if this "View" is selected from the Adapter so i can change the look of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a statelist drawable (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)) and customize the "selected" state to whatever you want there. Then you provide this drawable as the background for the item.